# I can't calculate the age in a class. Could someone please check?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Doing a homework right now. The task is to create a class for students. But for some reason, I can't calculate the age right there?

Have tried several methods but nothing works for me. Keep getting this error "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_date_today():
    return (2013, 10, 30)


dt = datetime(*get_date_today())

class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, birthdate, branch, grades):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.birthdate = birthdate
        self.branch = branch
        self.grades = grades

    def age(self):
        return (datetime(*get_date_today()) - datetime(*self.birthdate())).days/365

    def print_details(self):
        print("Name:", self.name)
        print("Grades:", self.grades)
        print('Age: ', self.age())
        print('Branch: ', self.branch)
        print('Grades:', self.grades)


Will = Student('Will', 'Smith', (2001,10,12), 'Philosophy', [12,11,10,10,9,8])
print(Will.print_details())
```

Comment: *Where* do you get that error? Please cut this down to a [mcve] and include the traceback.

Comment: @jonsharpe The example seems perfectly reproductible to me, nothing wrong here

Comment: You might also want to look into a better way of getting todays date, that looks like it'd be a royal PITA to maintain

Comment: @olinox14 the thing wrong is that it's not *minimal*, there are two criteria there, plus as I said specifically it doesn't include the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Change `datetime(*self.birthdate())` to

```
datetime(*self.birthdate)
```

The property `self.birthdate` is a tuple/list, and not a function.

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'days'